# Xamarin forms messaging plugin

Tags: ios, xamarin, sms, xamarin.forms

I've just tested the "new" Xamarin forms cross platform plugin. It works as it should and you get navigation to the phones messaging app when you are about to send a message. As I could read it is restricted by the OS to not let you send sms from within the app directly, is this the same if you go all native to the NS api on iOS? A solution if you don't want to have the sms app enabled is to have a backend/api, but then it also requires more than just the app and a separate sms gateway. So my question is to know if there is a custom workaround to just send a sms if the user allowed it, directly from the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you can use `SmsManager` class to send an Sms. There is an example in [Xamarin's Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/sms/send_an_sms/) on how to do it.You need to add `SEND_SMS` permission. Here is the code snippet from the site

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage ("1234567890", null,"Hello from Xamarin.Android", null, null);
```

iOS does not allow us to Send an sms directly using an API alone. This is a restriction imposed by Apple. Recommended approach is use the default application installed in the iPhone. Best approach we can take to send message from within the App is to use the `MFMessageComposeViewController` class. With this we can present a UI (provided by iOS) within the App in which user can populate "Body" and "Recipient" fields and send Sms.

This [blog post](https://davidsonblake.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/send-mms-with-image-attachment-using-xamarin-ios/) has an example of how to use `MFMessageComposeViewController` in Xamarin

Comment: Ok, I'm using this plugin and as @Sreeraj points out, I meet the Apple restriction. What I wanted was a "No message app" display. And in that case I need to use another non app service to send my messages. Thanks top both of you

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 4 you can use `MFMessageComposeViewController` which shows interface for sending sms messages inside your app. You can use [PhoneService](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.iOS/Services/PhoneService.cs) class from [Xamarin-Forms-Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) project or [Xamarin.Plugins](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins) pcl library.

These projects also provide the same functionality for sending sms messages in Android.