# Send Xamarin.Forms (Android only) SMS without user interaction

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I couldn't get sending text messages without user interaction to work, i've scratched the web for it with no luck, am I missing something or it is not possible (yet).

**I made it in java (Android Studio)**
used `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: allowing a device to send texts without the user knowing about it would be a HUGE security flaw.  There are third party SMS services that have APIs you could use.

Comment: it is possible on android studio with java, I am creating an app that sends messages only.

Comment: If you are able to do it in Java you should be able to do it with Xamarin.  All of the Android APIs should be available.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Plugin.Messaging
var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
if (smsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground)
smsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground("+919999999999", "Test Message");
```

Comment: Maybe add which NuGet package to use for this code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the open source **"Xam.Plugins.Messaging"**  plugin and it work perfect in both platform IOS and android.

And here is code to send sms.

```
var smsMessenger = MessagingPlugin.SmsMessenger;
if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)
   smsMessenger.SendSms("+12121212111", "Hello");
```

Comment: this shows the sms interface, I want to send a message without user interaction, would you please read the question title

Comment: Without user interaction means it's opening out side the app ? In that case you have to use third party api like- http://www.twilio.com/sms and etc.

Comment: I want to send sms from my phone, not from a wep api, so my app dependes on the sim I have and also no need for internet

Comment: Above code work on Sim and even there is no need of Internet just check

Comment: but it shows interface, I need to send bulk messages, not just one

Comment: I haven't try that one check this link may be help you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590768/xamarin-forms-messaging-plugin

Comment: that's for Xamarin.Android, i don't know if I can use that code in xamarin forms

Comment: Not work on MAUI

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need this.
I tested it in **Xamarin Android**, haven't Testing in Xamarin.Forms.

> Manifest Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

> C# Code

```
    using Android.Telephony;

    public void sendSMS(string to,string msg)
    { 
        SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(to, null, msg, null, null); 
    }
```