# MAUI send sms without user interaction in Maui

Tags: sms, maui, .net-maui

I want to send a SMS in MAUI without opening the default messages App, I want to send the SMS silently in background. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: on iOS this is not possible without using a third party service.

Comment: on adroid, is it possible? how to implement it on android without opening the messages app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Xamarin.Forms (Android only) SMS without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653358/send-xamarin-forms-android-only-sms-without-user-interaction)

Comment: A solution for XF will most likely work for MAUI also, or can be adapted.  Don’t be rude to people who are trying to help you

Comment: i never used XF before. I will try to convert to MAUI the code you offered in the link thank for your help.

Comment: sorry to bump, but when i try to use `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` Package on MAUI, the project fails to build citing `android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy is defined multiple times`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation in MAUI.
Tested for Android and it works without opening the messages app. Here is the implementation for Android and iOS (not tested).
in the shared project create this class:

```
 public partial class SmsService
{
   public partial void Send(string address, string message);
}
```

Implementation for Android platform:

```
public partial class SmsService
{
    public partial void Send(string phonenbr, string message)
    {
        SmsManager smsM = SmsManager.Default;
        smsM.SendTextMessage(phonenbr, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Implementation for iOS platform (not tested):

```
public partial class SmsService
{
    public partial void Send(string address, string message)
    {
        if (!MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            return;

        MFMessageComposeViewController smsController = new MFMessageComposeViewController();

        smsController.Recipients = new[] { address };
        smsController.Body = message;
        EventHandler<MFMessageComposeResultEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            smsController.Finished -= handler;
            var uiViewController = sender as UIViewController;
            if (uiViewController == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sender");
            }
            uiViewController.DismissViewControllerAsync(true);
        };
        smsController.Finished += handler;
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(smsController, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: SmsManager could not be found. What package? What namespace?